# SQL populate Table from Database

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a problem with trying to populate a `jtable`. I have searched all over and cannot seem to find a solution to my code, I would appreciate any kind of help.

Here is the method I have to get the information:

```
public class MovieDAO extends Dao implements MovieDAOInterface{

    @Override
    public List<Movie> getAllMovies() {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            con = getConnection();

            String query = "Select * from Movie";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Movie AllMovies = new Movie(rs.getInt("MovieId"), rs.getString("MovieTitle"), rs.getString("MovieGenre"), rs.getInt("MovieLicence"));
                movies.add(AllMovies);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured in the getAllMovies() method");
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    freeConnection(con);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured in the finally section of the getAllMovies() method");
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        return movies;
    }
}
```

Here is where I am calling it and having the issue it wont display on the table;

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {                                         

    System.out.println("Test Find All Movies");
    MovieDAO dao = new MovieDAO();
    List<Movie> movies = dao.getAllMovies();
    if (movies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("List is empty");
    } else {
        for (Movie m : movies) {

            DisplayMovies.setModel(m.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _"I have searched all over"_ - Try some more by clicking the `abstracttablemodel` tag link. There you will find more examples. Or even `DefaultTableModel`. In General see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). There's a section on how to create table models

Comment: Don't perform query to db at AWT thread. Use SwingWorker for it.

Comment: Like the previous commentor. Understand how tables and table models work in Swing.